# I'm getting broken response from SOAP servies

Tags: android, soap, android-ksoap2

In my application I have used SOAP services, my issue is that I'm not receiving the full string response from the services. How to get full string ( large amount of data )or response from SOAP services.

Any one help me out. Thanks in advance.

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("customerId", "21738");
        request.addProperty("key", Global.KEY);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        // Make the soap call.
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        /*StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);*/
        try {

            // this is the actual part that will call the webservice
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
        SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
```

Comment: Post code snippets, data size..any info that might help us help you...plus try to use rest instead of SOAP.

Comment: ok, I will update the post.